# file upload issue in drupal, all files are submitted to /tmp instead of location stated

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Here is the code which I use to upload (drupal 6)

```
echo "DIR".$dir = drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename') . '/files';
if($docfile = file_save_upload('document',$dir))
    echo "success:".$docfile->filepath;
```

It shows output as success:/tmp/Winter_0.jpg and I see the file uploaded to /tmp folder instead of my modulename/files folder. Can any one help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling file_save_upload with the wrong parameters. Refer to the [file_save_upload API docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6) for the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the syntax correctly, the following oughta work:

```
echo "DIR".$dir = drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename') . '/files';
if($docfile = file_save_upload('document', null, $dir))
    echo "success:".$docfile->filepath;
```

Another possibility is that you need to tell Drupal that the file is not a temporary file.

```
file_set_status($file, FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT);
```

edit:

Just go with the link wimvds gave, read the docs, and test around what the correct syntax is. Perhaps the directory you are saving the file is wrong? Try /sites/all/files or /sites/default/files instead of trying to put it into the module folder where apache probably does not even have read/write rights, at least I'm unsure if Drupal lets us store files there.

Another take on reading the API would make me try `file_save_upload($yourfile, array(), $destination_directory, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);`

Comment: if($docfile = file_save_upload('document',null,$dir)) { file_set_status($docfile, FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT); echo "sucess".$docfile->filename; } I updated the code as stated above, this time I got a error as # warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Filename cannot be empty in /includes/file.inc on line 615. # warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpSPsHso' to '' in /includes/file.inc on line 615.